# How can i use a function in find_all() in BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm using bs4 for my project. Now I get something like:

```html
<tr flag='t'><td flag='f'></td></tr>
```

I already know i could use a function in find_all(). So i use

```
def myrule(tag):
    return tag['flag']=='f' and tag.parent['flag']=='t'; 
soup.find_all(myrule)
```

then i get the error like

```
KeyError: 'myrule'
```

can anyone help me with this, why it don't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching every possible tag in your soup object for an attribute named `flag`. If the current tag being passed don't have that attribute it'll throw an error and the program will stop.

You should initially verify if the tag have that attribute before checking the rest. Like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example = """<tr flag='t'><td flag='f'></td></tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, "lxml")

def myrule(tag):
  return "flag" in tag.attrs and tag['flag']=='f' and tag.parent['flag']=='t'; 

print(soup.find_all(myrule))
```

Outputs:

```
[<td flag="f"></td>]
```